# Why my code is executing faster if I click left mouse button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some procedure where it takes different amount of time to execute. If I do nothing it takes 5 times longer to execute. When I click left mouse button during execution of same procedure, it finishes after few seconds. Can anyone explain why that happens and how to prevent it from happening in future?

I have tried to set arrays in code to nothing.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim NumberOfCompanies As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String
    StartTime = Timer
    '////////////////////////////
    Sheets("Process").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ...
    Call Result
    ...
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Sheets("Result").Activate
    '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    LastRow = CountRow("Result", 1)
    NumberOfCompanies = Sheets("Result").Cells(LastRow, "A").Value
    MsgBox "There are " & NumberOfCompanies & " candidates for Nace change!" & " This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation
End Sub


Sub Result()
    Dim CompanyNumbersArray As Variant
    Dim StartingRow As Variant
    Dim EndingRow As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ArraySize As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim CompanyRows As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim Background As Boolean
    Dim CurrentCompany As String
    Dim NextCompany As String
    Dim Str As String
    Sheets("Process").Activate
    Sheets("Result").Range("A2:XFD1048576").Clear
    Sheets("NoResult").Range("A2:XFD1048576").Clear
    LastRow = CountRow("Process", 1)
    CompanyNumbersArray = Sheets("Process").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    StartingRow = Sheets("Process").Range("O2:O" & LastRow).Value
    EndingRow = Sheets("Process").Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Value
    Sheets("Process").Range("A2:S" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Range("A2:S" & LastRow)
    Sheets("Process").Range("A2:S" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NoResult").Range("A2:S" & LastRow)
    Sheets("Result").Range("A:T").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
    Sheets("NoResult").Range("A:T").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
    ArraySize = UBound(CompanyNumbersArray)
    Count = 1
    For i = 1 To ArraySize - 1
        CurrentCompany = CompanyNumbersArray(i, 1)
        NextCompany = CompanyNumbersArray(i + 1, 1)
        If CurrentCompany <> NextCompany Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    Str = "Result: Copying data to sheets /Result/ and /NoResult/ "
    Call ProgressOfCode(1, 4, Str)
    i = 1
    For j = 1 To Count
        Background = True
        CompanyRows = EndingRow(i, 1) - StartingRow(i, 1) + 1
        For k = 0 To CompanyRows - 1
            If (Sheets("Process").Range("R" & i + 1 + k).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone) Then
                Background = False
            Else
                Background = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Background = False Then
            Sheets("Result").Range("A" & StartingRow(i, 1) & ":T" & EndingRow(i, 1)).Value = vbNullString
            Sheets("Result").Range("A" & StartingRow(i, 1) & ":T" & EndingRow(i, 1)).Interior.Color = xlNone
        ElseIf Background = True Then
            Sheets("NoResult").Range("A" & StartingRow(i, 1) & ":T" & EndingRow(i, 1)).Value = vbNullString
            Sheets("NoResult").Range("A" & StartingRow(i, 1) & ":T" & EndingRow(i, 1)).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
        If EndingRow(i, 1) < LastRow Then
            i = EndingRow(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    Str = "Result: Copying data to sheets /Result/ and /NoResult/ "
    Call ProgressOfCode(2, 4, Str)
    Sheets("Result").Activate
    Sheets("Result").Range("A:T").Sort Key1:=Range("N2"), key2:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
    Sheets("NoResult").Activate
    Sheets("NoResult").Activate
    Sheets("NoResult").Range("A:T").Sort Key1:=Range("N2"), key2:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal
    Call ResultRestoreLines("Result")
    Str = "Result: Copying data to sheets /Result/ and /NoResult/ "
    Call ProgressOfCode(3, 4, Str)
    Call ResultRestoreLines("NoResult")
    Str = "Result: Copying data to sheets /Result/ and /NoResult/ "
    Call ProgressOfCode(4, 4, Str)
    Application.StatusBar = "Done!"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Private Sub ResultRestoreLines(SheetName As String)
    Dim CompanyNumbersArray As Variant
    Dim CompanyStructureArray As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ArraySize As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim CurrentCompany As String
    Dim NextCompany As String
    LastRow = CountRow(SheetName, 1)
    CompanyNumbersArray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
    CompanyStructureArray = Sheets(SheetName).Range("N2:N" & LastRow).Value
    ArraySize = UBound(CompanyNumbersArray)
    Count = 1
    For i = 1 To ArraySize - 1
        CurrentCompany = CompanyNumbersArray(i, 1)
        NextCompany = CompanyNumbersArray(i + 1, 1)
        If CurrentCompany <> NextCompany Then
            Count = Count + 1
        End If
    Next
    CurrentRow = 2
    For i = 1 To Count
        Sheets(SheetName).Range("A" & CurrentRow & ":P" & CurrentRow + CompanyStructureArray(CurrentRow - 1, 1) - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + CompanyStructureArray(CurrentRow - 1, 1)
    Next
    LastRow = CountRow(SheetName, 1)
    Sheets(SheetName).Cells(LastRow + 2, "A").Value = Count
End Sub
```

I would expect same code to run same amount of time.

Comment: Are the multiple `Sheets("Result").Activate` (and `NoResult`) necessary? I can't see a reason for them and it is always recommended to work without them if at all possible. I'm wondering if clicking the mouse is in some way activating the wrong (or right?) sheet and causing a difference.

Comment: I'm pretty sure at least one before sort is necessary(second is not necessary, probably was created while making post), otherwise it was giving some kind of error message. It does not seem to depend where I click. Sometimes I let it run in background and click on something in browser and it runs faster. One in main procedure are meant to activate sheet were Results are at the end. With what I should replace Sheets("Result").Activate?

Comment: You shouldn't need them at all, if all of your `.Range` etc. are fully qualified. I can see a couple of the `.Sort` in the `Result` sub that aren't qualified at all (`Key1` and `Key2`) and overall there's no qualification of *Workbook* - sort this out and I think you can remove them entirely.

Comment: I have removed all .Activate and .Select from code. I have added lines like this Workbooks("Strukturas.xlsm").Sheets("Process").Range("A" & LastRow).Value everywhere. However strange bug still exists.

Comment: Well, I can't explain the bug, but at least now your code is far more unlikely to be affected by the clicking of the screen - eg. the user selecting a cell when the macro is expecting the last cell *it* selected to still remain selected.